# RadioButtonLIst with option for "Other"

Tags: c#, radiobuttonlist

Any suggestions on how I would create a radio button list with an option for the user to input free text?

Here's a quick sample of what i'd be looking for:

- Red
- Blue
- Green
- Other (textbox would go here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at

- [RadioButtonList with TextBox](http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-1-0-1-1-basics/50946-radiobuttonlist-textbox.html)
- [ASP.Net RadioButtonList with
  TextBox](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t66435-radiobuttonlist-with-textbox.html)

Something like this

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdo" Runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>First</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Second</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Others <input type="text" name="txtOthers"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Having just looked at this, the above mark-up will not work when using a server-side tag. You'll get a Parser error:  "The 'Text' property of 'asp:ListItem' does not allow child objects."

Answer (score 1):

You could just have a Radio Button list and then when Other is selected in the event set the text box enabled otherwise disable it if it isn't the Other button.